# Understanding the mov instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

I don't understand what the `0x83443f` does. The value stored in `0x83443f` is 10, the value stored in `%eax` is 2, yet it gives 14 after it runs the line:

```
mov 0x83443f(,%eax,4), %eax
```

Answer (score 4):

The content of memory location 0x83443fh is **not used**.

The scaled addressing mode will multiply the contents of %eax (2) by 4 to obtain the address 0x83443fh + 8 = 0x834447h. This location's content will be moved to the %eax register.